# Can we find the address in the RAM knowing the data that is stored?

Tags: memory, ramdisk

Let's say we created an object with some programming language

```
a = "This is my text and it is very precious"
```

and then close the terminal.

As I understand it, the memory space that contain the information "This is my text and it is very precious" is not set back to a string of zeros. As a consequence the information is still there, but we just don't know where.

Let's assume we remember some information about this string. We remember that is starts with "This is my text and it is". **Is it possible to screen through the RAM to find out the address where this data is stored?**

Comment: Most operating systems protect against doing this.

Comment: Eventually garbage collection routine will reclaim and re-use that space so you have a limited window of opportunity.  Forensic programs can dump the RAM to a file but some regions of memory are protected.

Comment: windows throws memory addresses around, to protect vital information, good luck scanning your entire address space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming a virtual memory OS such as Linux, Windows, or MacOS...

Not from user mode. The entire address space of your process disappears when your process ends.

It is not even meaningful to ask for the physical address of your data while your process is still running, since it might change the moment after that information is returned to you.

From kernel mode it would be possible to painstakingly map a chunk of RAM into previously-unused kernel address space, search it, unmap it, repeat. However as cybernard mentions the RAM released by an ending process will likely soon be used by something else. And yes, it is overwritten, either with something else (if it's mapped to a file) or with zeroes before it's exposed to user mode. Also, if your string happened to cross the boundary of one of the chunks you're searching, you won't find it even if it's still in RAM.

What's the goal here?

Comment: There is no goal, just curiosity and the hope to better understand how RAM works. Thanks

Comment: @Remi.b You need to learn how virtual memory works too. How it really works, not just "stuff that won't fit in RAM will be kept in the pagefile".